# After receiving 400 extra reputation points, added to 185, how come 329 is the new total?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

Is the machine not good in math, or were my points taken away?

Bible quote, 'be kind, one to another'

Comment: Downvoting is not a bug, nor are you in a position to ask people to not do so. The voting system is [important to the function of the sites](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote). Look at the tool-tips on the vote buttons for some hints at why the votes might be. If you don't want downvotes then put some research in yourself before asking questions and make them clear and useful for others. This one is not likely to be usful in the future because it's only basis is that you just seem to have not read the links that came with the 400 points explaining what it was.

Comment: Also please stop with the useless comments. This isn't a chat room and things like ".........." are noise --- not useful for future site visitors. Comments are not for chit-chat. There is a chat site if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @Caleb-useless is a bit rough

Comment: It's rough but not unjustly so. Comments are third class citizens on the SE network and anything that does not either request or provide clarification on some point related to the post is considered noise. Even ones that do eventually are obsoleted by edits and removed. A comment with no content or purpose (such as your ".........." comment that I removed) is useless and we would all appriciate if you reserve the comment function for comments with some substance: again either asking for or suggesting clarifications in regard to the posts they are under.

Comment: @Caleb, I saw that my comment got erased, I wasn't sure what happened, so ........was a test to see if the machine ate my dots, as well.

Answer (score 7):

This question presents what is a formal logical fallacy: that of a false dilemma. Your account neither had points taken away nor is there a math error. The option not considered is that you've got your facts wrong.

The points you earned were association bonuses. Once you earn at least 200 points on any SE network site, you automatically get granted a new baseline rep of 100 points on all sites. This gets you past some of the new user restrictions and gives you basic privileges on all sites on the assumption that if you've figured out the basics on one site that knowledge should transfer.

Thus you earned 100 points on each of 4 sites. Your network aggregate rep will have gone up 400 but your rep on this site will only have gone up 100.

This and most other things pertaining to reputation are [explained in the help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: your comments downvotes and disqualifications of my posts could be greatly improved upon, esp. by adding a little love

Comment: @Hello Allow my to apologize if my tone has sometimes come across as harsh. Especially as far as this site goes I don't mind being blunt and calling a spade a spade, but I should at least make sure I do so respectfully. Please do understand that this site is not a social network or even a forum where the main interactions are relational. This is more of an academic environment—a collaboratively generated mini-encyclopedia—and the primary interactions are focused on content not people. Neither approval nor disapproval of posts here should be assumed to be about the people behind them.

Answer (score 4):

This page details your changes to rep, hopefully reviewing it will answer your question, if not perhaps you can be a bit more specific about what you think the problem is:

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/15134/hello?tab=reputation